# How to account value 1 in this matrix by considering some constraints

Tags: matlab

```
A = [0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0;
     1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

and then from the above matrix, I want to account value 1 which is not the same column with value >3. but it is not problem if only has one value which is the same column with value "1".

so i wish the result is

res = 2.

they are value "1" which is in first row and second row.

so what is its code to solve it??
thanks..

Comment: I can't understand this question.  Can you show us the simplest example which illustrates your problem, both input and output.  And show us the code you have which you want help with.

Comment: perhaps by 'account', you mean 'find'??

Comment: @GuntherStruyf : yeah 'find' I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow what you're asking about here.  You'd like to be able to know if a given column contains a value of `1` and no values `3` or greater.

This should get you started:

```
 for n = 1:size(A,2)
     if(~numel(find(A(:,n)>2)) && numel(find(A(:,n)==1)))
         disp('found')
     end
 end
```

---

To break down what is happening here.

The loop is designed to go through each column in the matrix `A`.

`numel` returns the number of elements that are in the matrix within the parens ().

`find` will return the index(s) of the element(s) that match the comparison criteria.  In the first case we're looking for elements greater than 2.  In the second elements that are equal to 1.  Since we are only sending a column of values (a vector) we will only get a vector in return to the `numel` call.

`numel` simply counts the number of items in that vector and returns that number.  If the vector is empty the number is 0.  I also use the fact that the `if` will interpret a 0 from `numel` as false so you won't execute what is within the `if` even if there are no values in the column greater than 2.

So if you want to know the number of `1`s in the column you simply use the numel(find(A(:,n)==1)) part of the if statement.

Comment: @Ben.A : but how many value "1" which is not same column with value ">3"??

Comment: Look into the use of `numel` that I have in the if statement.  The answer is already written for you there =P

Comment: @Ben.A: perhap me, I didn't understand what did you mean friend...can u explain to me? because i just want to know how many value "1" which its column there is not value ">3"?